# DOMPDF background color and image issue

Tags: css, pdf, dompdf

I got some issue with background in DOMPDF. Please assume an element having both a color and image background.

When i try with just color or image, both works. But when i want both, the background image work but the background color turn black. I tried these syntaxes :

```
background: #ff000 url('path/to/image');
// or
background-color: #ff000;
background-image: url('path/to/image');
```

The result is the same. I tried to check the html render without pdf and obviously it's works. The element is a div. The picture is a transparent PNG.

Edit : After posting this i thought about something : does even dompdf supports transparency in PNG for background ?

Answer (score 0):

dompdf v0.5.1 does not support alpha transparency. The most recent release ([v0.6.0](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.6.0)) does, as you can see here on the [dompdf demo site](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php#image_transparent_png.html,pdf).